# Edit CMakeLists.txt to compile with -fPIC

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to install drivers for a NOVINT Falcon called libnifalcon. I used cmake to create a make file, but when I run make I get the error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libnifalcon_cli_base.so  
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a(cmdline.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC  
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a: could not read symbols: Bad value  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
make[2]: ** [lib/libnifalcon_cli_base.so.1.0.1] Error 1  
make[1]: ** [src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED.dir/all] Error 2  
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've tried many of the techniques to compile usinf -fPIC but none have worked. Can anyone tell me where in the makefile, and what to write in order to compile using -fPIC?

The makefile is:

```
            # CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
            # Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 2.8

            # Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
            default_target: all
            .PHONY : default_target

            #=============================================================================
            # Special targets provided by cmake.

            # Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
            .SUFFIXES:

            # Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
            SUFFIXES =

            .SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

            # Suppress display of executed commands.
            $(VERBOSE).SILENT:

            # A target that is always out of date.
            cmake_force:
            .PHONY : cmake_force

            #=============================================================================
            # Set environment variables for the build.

            # The shell in which to execute make rules.
            #SHELL = /bin/sh

            # The CMake executable.
            CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

            # The command to remove a file.
            RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

            # The program to use to edit the cache.
            CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND = /usr/bin/ccmake

            # The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
            CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/mikewrock/Desktop/h3d/libnifalcon-1.0.1

            # The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
            CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/mikewrock/Desktop/h3d/libnifalcon-1.0.1/linux

            #=============================================================================
            # Targets provided globally by CMake.

            # Special rule for the target edit_cache
            edit_cache:
                @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
                /usr/bin/ccmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
            .PHONY : edit_cache

            # Special rule for the target edit_cache
            edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
            .PHONY : edit_cache/fast

            # Special rule for the target install
            install: preinstall
                @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
                /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
            .PHONY : install

            # Special rule for the target install
            install/fast: preinstall/fast
                @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
                /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
            .PHONY : install/fast

            # Special rule for the target install/local
            install/local: preinstall
                @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing only the local directory..."
                /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
            .PHONY : install/local

            # Special rule for the target install/local
            install/local/fast: install/local
            .PHONY : install/local/fast

            # Special rule for the target install/strip
            install/strip: preinstall
                @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing the project stripped..."
                /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
            .PHONY : install/strip

            # Special rule for the target install/strip
            install/strip/fast: install/strip
            .PHONY : install/strip/fast

            # Special rule for the target list_install_components
            list_install_components:
                @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Available install components are: \"Unspecified\""
            .PHONY : list_install_components

            # Special rule for the target list_install_components
            list_install_components/fast: list_install_components
            .PHONY : list_install_components/fast

            # Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
            rebuild_cache:
                @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
                /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
            .PHONY : rebuild_cache

            # Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
            rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
            .PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

            # The main all target
            all: cmake_check_build_system
                $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/mikewrock/Desktop/h3d/libnifalcon-1.0.1/linux/CMakeFiles /home/mikewrock/Desktop/h3d/libnifalcon-1.0.1/linux/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
                $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/mikewrock/Desktop/h3d/libnifalcon-1.0.1/linux/CMakeFiles 0
            .PHONY : all

            # The main clean target
            clean:
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
            .PHONY : clean

            # The main clean target
            clean/fast: clean
            .PHONY : clean/fast

            # Prepare targets for installation.
            preinstall: all
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
            .PHONY : preinstall

            # Prepare targets for installation.
            preinstall/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
            .PHONY : preinstall/fast

            # clear depends
            depend:
                $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
            .PHONY : depend

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named nifalcon_DEPEND

            # Build rule for target.
            nifalcon_DEPEND: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 nifalcon_DEPEND
            .PHONY : nifalcon_DEPEND

            # fast build rule for target.
            nifalcon_DEPEND/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f src/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_DEPEND.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_DEPEND.dir/build
            .PHONY : nifalcon_DEPEND/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named nifalcon_SHARED

            # Build rule for target.
            nifalcon_SHARED: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 nifalcon_SHARED
            .PHONY : nifalcon_SHARED

            # fast build rule for target.
            nifalcon_SHARED/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f src/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_SHARED.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_SHARED.dir/build
            .PHONY : nifalcon_SHARED/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named nifalcon_STATIC

            # Build rule for target.
            nifalcon_STATIC: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 nifalcon_STATIC
            .PHONY : nifalcon_STATIC

            # fast build rule for target.
            nifalcon_STATIC/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f src/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_STATIC.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_STATIC.dir/build
            .PHONY : nifalcon_STATIC/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named nifalcon_cli_base_DEPEND

            # Build rule for target.
            nifalcon_cli_base_DEPEND: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 nifalcon_cli_base_DEPEND
            .PHONY : nifalcon_cli_base_DEPEND

            # fast build rule for target.
            nifalcon_cli_base_DEPEND/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_cli_base_DEPEND.dir/build.make src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_cli_base_DEPEND.dir/build
            .PHONY : nifalcon_cli_base_DEPEND/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED

            # Build rule for target.
            nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED
            .PHONY : nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED

            # fast build rule for target.
            nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED.dir/build.make src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED.dir/build
            .PHONY : nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named nifalcon_cli_base_STATIC

            # Build rule for target.
            nifalcon_cli_base_STATIC: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 nifalcon_cli_base_STATIC
            .PHONY : nifalcon_cli_base_STATIC

            # fast build rule for target.
            nifalcon_cli_base_STATIC/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_cli_base_STATIC.dir/build.make src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_cli_base_STATIC.dir/build
            .PHONY : nifalcon_cli_base_STATIC/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named nifalcon_device_boost_thread_DEPEND

            # Build rule for target.
            nifalcon_device_boost_thread_DEPEND: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 nifalcon_device_boost_thread_DEPEND
            .PHONY : nifalcon_device_boost_thread_DEPEND

            # fast build rule for target.
            nifalcon_device_boost_thread_DEPEND/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_device_boost_thread_DEPEND.dir/build.make src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_device_boost_thread_DEPEND.dir/build
            .PHONY : nifalcon_device_boost_thread_DEPEND/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named nifalcon_device_boost_thread_SHARED

            # Build rule for target.
            nifalcon_device_boost_thread_SHARED: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 nifalcon_device_boost_thread_SHARED
            .PHONY : nifalcon_device_boost_thread_SHARED

            # fast build rule for target.
            nifalcon_device_boost_thread_SHARED/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_device_boost_thread_SHARED.dir/build.make src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_device_boost_thread_SHARED.dir/build
            .PHONY : nifalcon_device_boost_thread_SHARED/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named nifalcon_device_boost_thread_STATIC

            # Build rule for target.
            nifalcon_device_boost_thread_STATIC: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 nifalcon_device_boost_thread_STATIC
            .PHONY : nifalcon_device_boost_thread_STATIC

            # fast build rule for target.
            nifalcon_device_boost_thread_STATIC/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_device_boost_thread_STATIC.dir/build.make src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_device_boost_thread_STATIC.dir/build
            .PHONY : nifalcon_device_boost_thread_STATIC/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named barrow_mechanics

            # Build rule for target.
            barrow_mechanics: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 barrow_mechanics
            .PHONY : barrow_mechanics

            # fast build rule for target.
            barrow_mechanics/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f examples/CMakeFiles/barrow_mechanics.dir/build.make examples/CMakeFiles/barrow_mechanics.dir/build
            .PHONY : barrow_mechanics/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named falcon_led

            # Build rule for target.
            falcon_led: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 falcon_led
            .PHONY : falcon_led

            # fast build rule for target.
            falcon_led/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f examples/CMakeFiles/falcon_led.dir/build.make examples/CMakeFiles/falcon_led.dir/build
            .PHONY : falcon_led/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named falcon_test_cli

            # Build rule for target.
            falcon_test_cli: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 falcon_test_cli
            .PHONY : falcon_test_cli

            # fast build rule for target.
            falcon_test_cli/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f examples/CMakeFiles/falcon_test_cli.dir/build.make examples/CMakeFiles/falcon_test_cli.dir/build
            .PHONY : falcon_test_cli/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named findfalcons

            # Build rule for target.
            findfalcons: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 findfalcons
            .PHONY : findfalcons

            # fast build rule for target.
            findfalcons/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f examples/CMakeFiles/findfalcons.dir/build.make examples/CMakeFiles/findfalcons.dir/build
            .PHONY : findfalcons/fast

            #=============================================================================
            # Target rules for targets named findfalcons_multi

            # Build rule for target.
            findfalcons_multi: cmake_check_build_system
                $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 findfalcons_multi
            .PHONY : findfalcons_multi

            # fast build rule for target.
            findfalcons_multi/fast:
                $(MAKE) -f examples/CMakeFiles/findfalcons_multi.dir/build.make examples/CMakeFiles/findfalcons_multi.dir/build
            .PHONY : findfalcons_multi/fast

            # Help Target
            help:
                @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
                @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
                @echo "... clean"
                @echo "... depend"
                @echo "... edit_cache"
                @echo "... install"
                @echo "... install/local"
                @echo "... install/strip"
                @echo "... list_install_components"
                @echo "... rebuild_cache"
                @echo "... nifalcon_DEPEND"
                @echo "... nifalcon_SHARED"
                @echo "... nifalcon_STATIC"
                @echo "... nifalcon_cli_base_DEPEND"
                @echo "... nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED"
                @echo "... nifalcon_cli_base_STATIC"
                @echo "... nifalcon_device_boost_thread_DEPEND"
                @echo "... nifalcon_device_boost_thread_SHARED"
                @echo "... nifalcon_device_boost_thread_STATIC"
                @echo "... barrow_mechanics"
                @echo "... falcon_led"
                @echo "... falcon_test_cli"
                @echo "... findfalcons"
                @echo "... findfalcons_multi"
            .PHONY : help



            #=============================================================================
            # Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

            # Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
            # No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
            # because they might be regenerated.
            cmake_check_build_system:
                $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
            .PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Thanks for your help
-Michael

EDIT: As recommended, I've tried modifying CMakeLists.txt instead of the makefiles it generates. I'm still having the same issue, so here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
            ######################################################################################
            # CMake directives
            ######################################################################################

            #Require 2.6 or higher. 
            CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6.0 FATAL_ERROR)

            #See if we've got our cmake modules checked out. If not, advise to do so.
            IF(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../compily_buildd/cmake")
              SET(BUILDSYS_CMAKE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../compily_buildd/cmake")
              MESSAGE(STATUS "Using outside compily_buildd directory ${BUILDSYS_CMAKE_DIR}")
            ELSEIF(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compily_buildd/cmake")
              SET(BUILDSYS_CMAKE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compily_buildd/cmake")
              MESSAGE(STATUS "Using compily_buildd git submodule ${BUILDSYS_CMAKE_DIR}")
            ELSE(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compily_buildd/cmake")
              MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR 
                "Cannot find compily_buildd directory for np labs project compilation functions.\n"
                "Make sure you've either put the compily_buildd directory in the same root as your repository directory, or that you've used the compily_buildd submodule (git submodule update --init).\n"
                "NP Labs build repository is available at git://github.com/qdot/compily_buildd.git"
                )
            ENDIF(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../compily_buildd/cmake")

            LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${BUILDSYS_CMAKE_DIR})

            INCLUDE( ${BUILDSYS_CMAKE_DIR}/BuildSysCMakeLib.cmake )

            #setting link directory policy

            IF(COMMAND cmake_policy)
              CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0003 NEW)
            ENDIF(COMMAND cmake_policy)

            ######################################################################################
            # Project declaration and options
            ######################################################################################

            #Project declaration

            PROJECT(LIBNIFALCON)
            set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
            set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
            set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC"  )
            INITIALIZE_BUILD()

            #Common Options

            OPTION_LIBRARY_BUILD_STATIC(ON)
            #We can't build shared on MSVC yet
            IF(NOT MSVC)
              OPTION_LIBRARY_BUILD_SHARED(ON)
            ENDIF(NOT MSVC)
            OPTION_FAST_MATH(ON)
            OPTION_ARCH_OPTS(ON)
            OPTION_GPROF(OFF)
            #OPTION_LOG4CXX(OFF LIBNIFALCON_REQ_LIBS)
            #OPTION_CREATE_VERSION_FILE(ON "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/version.cc")

            #Project specific options

            OPTION(FORCE_FTD2XX_BUILD "Force building FTD2XX libraries on non-windows platforms" OFF)
            OPTION(STATIC_LINK_SUFFIXES "Add a symbolic link with [library_name]_s on static libraries (for ease in building staticly linked binaries under gcc)" OFF)
            OPTION(BUILD_SWIG_BINDINGS "Build Java/Python bindings for libnifalcon" OFF)
            OPTION(BUILD_EXAMPLES "Build libnifalcon examples" ON)

            ######################################################################################
            # Project specific package finding
            ######################################################################################

            #Find communications libraries
            IF(WIN32 OR FORCE_FTD2XX_BUILD)
              FIND_PACKAGE(libftd2xx)
              IF(LIBFTD2XX_FOUND)
                INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBFTD2XX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
                SET(LIBNIFALCON_REQ_LIBS ${LIBFTD2XX_LIBRARIES})
              ENDIF(LIBFTD2XX_FOUND)
            ENDIF(WIN32 OR FORCE_FTD2XX_BUILD)

            IF(NOT LIBFTD2XX_FOUND)
              FIND_PACKAGE(libusb-1.0)
              IF(LIBUSB_1_FOUND)
                INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS})
                SET(LIBNIFALCON_REQ_LIBS ${LIBUSB_1_LIBRARIES})
              ENDIF(LIBUSB_1_FOUND)
            ENDIF(NOT LIBFTD2XX_FOUND)

            IF(NOT LIBFTD2XX_FOUND AND NOT LIBUSB_1_FOUND)
              MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Either ftd2xx or libusb-1.0 is required to build libnifalcon. Check the README file for info.")
            ENDIF(NOT LIBFTD2XX_FOUND AND NOT LIBUSB_1_FOUND)

            #Find boost, used all over the place
            SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
            SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

            FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED)
            IF(NOT Boost_FOUND)
              MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "libnifalcon requires a minimum of the Boost 1.33 headers to build")
            ENDIF(NOT Boost_FOUND)

            FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS program_options thread)

            ######################################################################################
            # Project specific globals
            ######################################################################################

            #library definitions

            SET(LIBNIFALCON_MAJOR_VERSION 1)
            SET(LIBNIFALCON_MINOR_VERSION 0)
            SET(LIBNIFALCON_BUILD_VERSION 1)

            # BUILDSYS_CPACK_INFO(
            #   NAME "libnifalcon"
            #   MAJOR_VERSION ${LIBNIFALCON_MAJOR_VERSION}
            #   MINOR_VERSION ${LIBNIFALCON_MINOR_VERSION}
            #   BUILD_VERSION ${LIBNIFALCON_BUILD_VERSION}
            #   VENDOR "Nonpolynomial Labs"
            #   DESCRIPTION "Open Source Driver for the Novint Falcon Haptic Controller"
            #   )
            # INCLUDE(CPack)

            SET(LIBNIFALCON_VERSION ${LIBNIFALCON_MAJOR_VERSION}.${LIBNIFALCON_MINOR_VERSION}.${LIBNIFALCON_BUILD_VERSION})

            #library name definitions

            CREATE_LIBRARY_LINK_NAME(nifalcon)
            CREATE_LIBRARY_LINK_NAME(nifalcon_cli_base)
            CREATE_LIBRARY_LINK_NAME(nifalcon_device_boost_thread)

            SET(LIBNIFALCON_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

            INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBNIFALCON_INCLUDE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
            LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})

            #If we build libusb staticly on apple, we need the proper frameworks
            IF(BUILD_STATIC AND APPLE)
              LIST(APPEND LIBNIFALCON_EXE_LINK_LIBS "-framework IOKit" "-framework CoreFoundation")
            ENDIF(BUILD_STATIC AND APPLE)

            LIST(APPEND LIBNIFALCON_EXE_LINK_LIBS 
              ${libnifalcon_LIBRARY}
              ${LIBNIFALCON_REQ_LIBS}
              )

            ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(include)
            ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)
            IF(BUILD_EXAMPLES)
              ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(examples)
            ENDIF(BUILD_EXAMPLES)
            IF(BUILD_SWIG_BINDINGS)
              ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lang/swig)
            ENDIF(BUILD_SWIG_BINDINGS)

            # pkg-config (use the CPack information)
            # FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig)
            # if(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
            #   set(PC_SHORT_NAME "${BUILDSYS_CPACK_NAME}")
            #   set(PC_LONG_NAME "${BUILDSYS_CPACK_NAME}")
            #   set(PC_LIBRARY_NAME "${LIBNIFALCON_CPP}")
            #   set(PC_DESCRIPTION "${CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY}")
            #   set(PC_VERSION "${LIBNIFALCON_MAJOR_VERSION}.${LIBNIFALCON_MINOR_VERSION}.${LIBNIFALCON_BUILD_VERSION}")

            #   if(LIBUSB_1_FOUND)
            #     set(PC_REQUIRES "${PC_REQUIRES}libusb-1.0 ")
            #     set(PC_LINK_FLAGS "${PC_LINK_FLAGS}-lnifalcon_comm_libusb ")
            #   endif(LIBUSB_1_FOUND)

            #   set(PC_LINK_FLAGS "${lib${PC_LIBRARY_NAME}_LINK_FLAGS} ${PC_LINK_FLAGS}")
            #   set(PC_LINK_FLAGS "-l${PC_LIBRARY_NAME} ${PC_LINK_FLAGS}")
            #   set(PC_COMPILE_FLAGS "${lib${PC_LIBRARY_NAME}_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
            #   set(PC_CONFIGURED_FILE
            #     ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libnifalcon.pc
            #     )
            #   MESSAGE("-- Generating ${PC_CONFIGURED_FILE}")
            #   configure_file(
            #     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libnifalcon.pc.cmake
            #     ${PC_CONFIGURED_FILE}
            #     @ONLY
            #     )
            #   set(PKG_CONFIG_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig")
            #   install(FILES ${PC_CONFIGURED_FILE} DESTINATION ${PKG_CONFIG_DIR})
            # endif(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to edit the makefile, when it says right at the top `CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!`?  You should be editing the `CMakeLists.txt` file, and you should tag your question for `cmake` instead of `make`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following to the Makefile.

```
CFLAGS += -fPIC
CPPFLAGS += -fPIC
```

But, really, you should be modifying the code for cmake, and then regenerate the Makefile. There should be a way to add to CFLAGS in cmake.

EDIT: Seems like you can set the cmake variables CMAKE_C_FLAGS and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in the cmake input file.

Comment: I tried modifying the makefile to no avail, but I think you're right with the setting the flags in CMakeLists.txt

I've added the lines:
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC"  )
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fPIC"  )

to CMakeLists.txt but I still get the same error, somehow I feel the -fPIC flag is being lost

Answer (score 3):

The issue was SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) in the CMakeLists.txt, when changed to SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF), the makefile worked fine.

Thanks to everyone for their help

Answer (score 0):

I thing your are linking against the wrong boost library (libboost_program_options-mt.a). It is static (.a) and possibly not compiled using fPIC. Try using the shared version (.so).

Comment: I found that libboost_program_options-mt.a links to libboost_program_options.a, so I tried changing the link to libboost_program_options.so and I get the following error:

/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libnifalcon_cli_base.so.1.0.1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/util/CMakeFiles/nifalcon_cli_base_SHARED.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: First of all in your CMakeLists.txt you set `SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)`. I guess this is the reason CMake chose the static version of libboost_program_options. Secondly, did you change **file system** link of libboost_program_options-mt.a to point to libboost_program_options.so? I think this is a bad idea. I think most of your problems are related to CMake settings. What OS are you using for compilation?

Comment: The issue was SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON),I changed it to SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) and now it's working. Thank you very much for your help!